# Does Excel.Range class have a member function called Cells

Tags: c#

```
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
```

`"xlRange.Cells[i, j]"` -  does that mean `Cells` is a member function in class `xlRange`?

Can anyone explain what's happening in this statement:

```
(xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
```

It checks that the first object xlRange.Cells[i, j] is not null, then because thats not null it can check if value2 is null, otherwise if it checked for value2 being null it would get an error because the object itself is null.

Comment: we are using dot operator to get the cells inside range does that mean cells is a function in xlRange?If no then what does .cells refer to?

Comment: it could be a function, it could be a property.. either way, actually matters not to you.  in this case, without checking, its most likely a property

Comment: we are not using parenthesis to consider it as a property but instead we are using  indexers...does that mean it is a class??I am new to c#...so please help me with it.

Comment: It can still be a property, it just has indexers.  Either way, its not relevant really what it is, only what it gives you

Answer (score 0):

Cells is not a function, is an array property of Excel.Range class.

Following statement checks whether the workbook has a cell in the row i and column j if so, the value in the row i and column j is not null.

Comment: If no then what does .cells refer to?what is array property of Excel.Range class?Can u please eloborate it?